# Monitor specific disk spaces on Jenkins nodes

Tags: jenkins

Currently Jenkins master can do a "preventive monitoring" of the nodes in the "/computer/configure" page but it is only possible to monitor 2 disk spaces :

- $JENKINS_HOME
- Temp Space

I would like to monitor other disk spaces. For example, the /var/lib/docker (default directory where all docker images are pulled) is quickly full and causes some error on the nodes.

As we use the EC2 slaves plugin, it will be useful to be able to specify a threshold for this space size in order to put the node "offline" when the threshold is reached.. The EC2 instance will then be destroyed and another "healthy" slave will be started if needed.

Is it currently possible to achieve this in Jenkins ?

Version : Jenkins ver. 2.89.1

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that Jenkins monitors only those directories out of the box. The code handling this is at `hudson.node_monitors.TemporarySpaceMonitor` and `hudson.node_monitors.DiskSpaceMonitor`.

It would be fairly easy to implement a new `NodeMonitor` that would accept a list of directories to watch and would use the Jenkins plugins framework facility to take a node down if the space goes below a defined limit. I could even imagine a new plugin that would offer a series of enhanced node monitors. The plan has even been to extract all node monitors into a dedicated plugin since long, but this wasn't completed for various reasons (cf. [JENKINS-26466](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26466) for details).

I wrote such a plugin at https://github.com/jenkinsci/inodes-monitor-plugin if you are looking for an example on how to use the `NodeMonitor` API.